# Jenkins and Xcode 8: Failed to copy PNG files

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, png, jenkins-plugins

Getting this error since trying to use Xcode 8 with Jenkins. Never had this before and Xcode 8 on the same machine compiles just fine, so we're only getting this in Jenkins. Does somebody know why? We're using the Xcode Integration plugin v1.4.11 for iOS build jobs.

This is the error message in Jenkins' log:

```
15:04:16 ** BUILD FAILED **
15:04:16 
15:04:16 
15:04:16 The following build commands failed:
15:04:16    CopyPNGFile /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Project_iOS_Build_Release_Branch/workspace/builds/dev_staging/SomeAssets.bundle/icon_cart.png SomewPod/Something/Assets/icon_cart.png
```

I found out that this seems to happen for all assets in a pod asset bundle, no matter which one. For some reason when compiling with Jenkins the pod assets are not copied to the Jenkins temporary workspace location.

Any Jenkins/Xcode experts around that have any knowledge about this? This issue is seriously affecting our build pipeline.

**EDIT:** I found out that this command fails first in Jenkins:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copypng -compress -strip-PNG-text /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iOS_Test/workspace/Pods/FooPod/Foo/Assets/foo.png /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iOS_Test/workspace/builds/dev_staging/FooAssets.bundle/foo.png
```

but when I run this in the terminal it executes successfully and copies the file. Why would this fails suddenly with Jenkins?

**EDIT2:**

I stumbled over this line in the Jenkins log output:

```
execvP: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin: path too long
```

It seems that there is an issue with Jenkins with long path names. That would explain why this issue only occurs with Jenkins, not with Xcode.

Since I cannot reduce the path name character length, I wonder are there any known workarounds for this Jenkins issue?

Comment: Have you tried running `xcode-select -switch <path to Xcode 8.app>/contents/developer`? This will ensure that Jenkins builds with the new Xcode 8 command line tools. The only other thing I can think of would be to make sure you enable the clean before build feature so that you have a fresh copy to build with.

Comment: @werm098 did the `sudo xcode-select -switch <path to Xcode 8.app>/contents/developer` but it didn't help. Also, clean is done before every build.

Comment: I am having the same kind of issue on a brand new machine with Xcode 8 (not through Jenkins).